# Using Rewrite for different folders

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have all my php files on the root folder, and I use this Rewrite Rule, which works fine:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /broken.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index(\.(html|htm)))?$
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} / [L,R,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index(\.(html|htm)))?$
RewriteRule ^([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

I currently plan to modify it so I can rewrite query strings such as contact/test/yes becomes contact.php?test=yes

My question is this: if I have a sub folder that I need rewrite on (for example root/subfolder1); how do I rewrite the rule in this subfolder1 such that something like `contact/test/yes` would not be interpreted as a yes file that's inside a test folder, which is inside a contact folder?

Thanks for all the previous help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can either create each case or having dynamic

note: if a folder exists and you need to add this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

if you create each case you will have to specify each sub folder like:

```
RewriteRule ^contact/test/([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /contact.php?test=$1 [L,QSA]
```

if do you it dynamically you will have to process each page in a main php file then create a logic in that file to parse the correct info:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2&lastpage=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: So, the rules in the outer folder will not override the rule in the inner folder? Thanks

Comment: outer folder? inner folder? I'm sorry i'm not following you

Comment: What I meant is this: if a request follows a rule on the root folder, and the same request also follows another rule in a subfolder (e.g. /contact/), which of the 2 rules will be applied to the request? Will it be like a cascading effect, such that the last rule always apply? Or will it be the first rule that is applied?

Comment: yes it will follow, if you want to avoid these issues you need to add this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d (i updated my answer)

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer all my questions. Hopefully, if I have other questions, you'll be around to answer them too.

Comment: What does the flags d and f mean?

Comment: f = file and d = directory, ! = not, so in this case not file and not directory